# nginx redirect what is not coming from load balancing

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I have **nginx** on **SERVER1** that is acting as load balancing between **SERVER1** and **SERVER2**

in **SERVER1** I have the upstream for the load balancing defined as :

```
upstream server
    # SELF SERVER1 [localhost]
    server 127.0.0.1:8082 weight=3 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=2;
    # other SERVER2
    server otherserverip:8082 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=2;
}
```

The load balancing config on **SERVER1** is this one:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name ~^(de|es|fr)\.server\.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass   http://server;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        # trying to pass a variable in the header to SERVER2
        proxy_set_header        Is-From-Load-Balancer 1;        
    }
}
```

Then in **SERVER2** I have:

```
server {
    listen   8082;
    server_name localhost;
    root   /var/www/server.com/public;
    # test output values
    add_header testloadbalancer $http_is_from_load_balancer;
    add_header testloadbalancer2 not_load_bal;

    ## other stuff here to process the request
}
```

I can see the "testloadbalancer" in the response header is set to 1 when the request is coming from the load balancing, it is not present when from a direct access: **SERVER2:8082** .

I would like to bounce back to the **SERVER1** all the direct requests that are sent to **SERVER2**, but keep the ones from the load balancing. So this should forbid direct access to **SERVER2:8082** and redirect to **SERVER1:80** .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a working solution by following the examples here on multiple if conditions in nginx [ http://rosslawley.co.uk/2010/01/nginx-how-to-multiple-if-statements/ ] :

in **SERVER2**

```
server {
  listen   8082;
  server_name localhost;
  root   /var/www/server.com/public;

  set $is_load_balancer FALSE;
  if ( $http_is_from_load_balancer ) {
    set $is_load_balancer TRUE;
  }

  if ( $is_load_balancer = FALSE )  {
    # here you redirect to the server.com 
    # so this will be processed again by the load balancing 
    rewrite ^ http://server.com$request_uri? permanent;  
  }    
}
```